# Telerik AllowedExtension doesn't filter the file to select

Tags: telerik, telerik-blazor

I am trying to validate the File Select
example link here [Telerik File Select](https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/components/fileselect/validation)
but the AllowedExtension list doesn't filter

This is the given example code of Telerik

```
@* Some images are only allowed, min size 1KB, max size 4MB *@

<div style="width:300px">
    <TelerikFileSelect AllowedExtensions="@AllowedExtensions"
                       MinFileSize="@MinSize"
                       MaxFileSize="@MaxSize">
    </TelerikFileSelect>
    <div class="k-form-hint">
        Expected files: <strong> JPG, PNG, JPEG </strong> between <strong>1KB</strong> and <strong>4MB</strong>.
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    public List<string> AllowedExtensions { get; set; } = new List<string>() { ".jpg", ".png", ".jpeg" };

    public int MinSize { get; set; } = 1024;

    public int MaxSize { get; set; } = 4 * 1024 * 1024;
}
```